# MultipeerConnectivity Session management

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I am really stuck at the moment trying to get the grasp of invites in the MultipeerConnectivityFramework.

Right now I have an ipad App acting as the Advertiser and an iphone App acting as Browser.
I have implemented a sharedService for the MultipeerFramework and did the following:

**Advertiser**

```objc
@implementation MultipeerConnectivityService {
    MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *_advertiser;
    MCSession *_session;
    MCNearbyServiceBrowser *_browser;        
}

- (void)automaticAdvertiseWithName:(NSString *)name {
    MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:name];
    _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerID];
    _session.delegate = self;

    _advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:peerID discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:kServiceType];
    _advertiser.delegate = self;
    [_advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
}

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler {
    invitationHandler([@YES boolValue], _session);
    NSLog(@"Invitation accepted");
}
```

**Browser**

```objc
- (void)automaticBrowsingWithName:(NSString *)name {
    MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:name];
    _browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:peerID serviceType:kServiceType];
    _browser.delegate = self;
    [_browser startBrowsingForPeers];
}

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser didNotStartBrowsingForPeers:(NSError *)error {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(browser:didNotStartBrowsingForPeers:)]) {
        [_delegate browserDidNotStartBrowsingForPeers];
    }
}
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:[self getMCSession] withContext:nil timeout:10];
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(browser:foundPeer:)]) {
        [_delegate browser:browser foundPeer:peerID];
    }
}
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(browserLostPeer:)]) {
        [_delegate browserLostPeer:peerID];
    }
}

- (MCSession *) getMCSession {
    return _session;
}
```

But then I am getting as feedback in the console:

```objc
-[MCNearbyServiceBrowser invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:] Bad argument session=nil
```

When I check for the found Advertisers, everything is OK. My advertiser ipad is being found. But how can I manage the invite?

So I don't get it right now... When I send an invitation by the browser, what session do I have to use? On the iPad I set up the session like you can see in the "automaticAdvertiseWithName" method. but on the iphone I don't do this when calling "automaticBrowsingWithName"... Is that the problem? And don't they have to be the same session to successfully connect them? And how can I successfully invite my advertiser ipad to the browser?

I am confused by the notion of creating a new session when one has already been created by the advertiser.

I am actually not sure, if the delegate didReceiveInvitation is adding the peer to the connectedPeers at all.

```objc
- (void)automaticAdvertiseWithName:(NSString *)name {
    MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:name];
    self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerID];
    self.session.delegate = self;
    _advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:peerID discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:kServiceType];
    _advertiser.delegate = self;
    [_advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
}
- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler {
    BOOL accept = YES;
    invitationHandler(accept, self.session);
    NSLog(@"Invitation accepted: %@", self.session);
}
```

And when I call the property "connectedPeers" on my session, there are no connected peers at all, even though the delegate found one. Did I make a mistake there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your session is null at the time you call invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout...Anyway you have two options to fix this.

You have two options :
***Option 1***
- move the *peerID creation*, *session creation* and *session delegate assignment* in a place where its executed at all time. For example in the init code for MultipeerConnectivityService class of if its a UIViewController in the viewDidLoad.
***Option 2***
- add the following snippet before you call "invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:"

```
if (!_session) {
      MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"Browser"]; // you can customize the name here
     _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerID];
     _session.delegate = self;
}
```

Hope this helps ...good luck!

Comment: Thanks!! I went for option 2 and it works perfectly fine! The session concept was a little bit hard to wrap my brain around at first. I always thought I would have to use the SAME session for both....

Comment: Glad option 2 helped!

Comment: I get confused with this too. I know a browser is meant to add peers to its session, but I'm still not sure what the advertiser is meant to do by right. At the moment I'm just assuming that when the advertiser provides a session in `invitationHandler`, that somehow gets "merged" with the session that the browser is adding it to. @Beuz or @ISARFAKTOR, if you have insights to this, please do share.

Comment: Actually the way I see it is that although you usually code for the browsing logic as well as the advertising logic in the same class, when the program is used you have two different devices with 1 totally independent session each. <br/>From there, the browser discovers the advertised session and invites the advertiser to participate in its own session. The rest happens in the browser's session. The advertiser at this point is just a participant in the browser's session.

Comment: I agree its a bit confusing because you would think that the advertiser would be something like a server that people would join. But the way it seems to be is just a way of showing your presence so that others can invite you...Hope this helps.